# Java LocalDate invalid date formatting

Tags: java, date, localdate, localdatetime

I have a script to get previous month for current date (*script executed on 1st date monthly*) the script return valid result for all other month except on **January**

I tried to reproduce the case with these script

```
import java.time.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1); 
    LocalDate prevMonth = today.minusDays(1); 
    
    System.out.println("Date object " + prevMonth);
    System.out.println("Date formatted " + prevMonth.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Date object 2021-12-31
Date formatted 2022-12-31
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5WQv.png)

Environment

```
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Where is the bug come from, or you have better idea ?

PS: I preferred LocalDate over calendar

Comment: Did you check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see what `Y` and `D` represent?

Comment: I really missed that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to carefully read the docs.

**Do not use `Y`**.

Y means 'weekyear'. You really, really, *really* do not want this. It'll turn 2022 somewhere *around* jan 1st, but not on jan 1st (well, one it about 7 years or so, it manages to line up perfectly). There will be days in year X that have a weekyear of year (X+1), and there will be days in year Z that will have a weekyear of year (Z-1): After all, a week starts on monday, so 'weekyear' can't change except on mondays. Turns out Jan 1st? Not always a Monday.

**You want `u`**. `y` is always great, but y does silly things for years before the year 0. Aside from that, `u` and `y` are identical. In other words, `u` is just better, it's the one you should use.

**You also do not want `D`**.

D means day-of-year. You wanted day-of-month. That's the symbol `d` (lowercase).

**Try `"uuuu-MM-dd"`**.

Comment: wow I missed that. thanks for your great answer and remembering me to the some basic things. case closed.

Answer (score -1):

Uppercase 'D' is Day of year, not day of month.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

You are likely looking for 'd' - Day of Month.
`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")`

Comment: This is a dangerous half-answer (it has omitted the `Y` problem, and that's the sneaky one that causes millions of dollars worth of damage, hence, this is a dangerous answer).

Comment: well thanks for correction, it's my bad on reproducing script, you're right.